# Increment a Label

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, increment

I have a problem with my program, I need to `INCREMENT` the value of a certain `Label`

```
 Dim p1num As Integer = 0
 M.Text = Format(Now, "MM")
 Y.Text = Format(Now, "yy")

txtPNumber.Text = Y.Text.ToString & M.Text.ToString & p1num.ToString("D4")
```

I use this to generate the Patient ID, where in the M is for Month and the Y is for Year + the p1num to create a 4 digit number.... so the output will be like this:

(Let use the current date and year)

```
13020001
13020002
13020003
13020004
```

and so on....

After this, I will use these codes to insert it to my DB in SQL SERVER :

```
Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection
        Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader
        Try
            SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=####;" & _
"Initial Catalog=####;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password="
            Dim SQLcmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Patients" & _
                                         "(pIDNo)" & _
                                         "VALUES(@pIDNo)", SQLcon)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIDNo", txtPNumber.Text)
 MsgBox("Patient Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured, Can't Add Patient!" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLcon.Close()
        End Try
        Return ""
```

the problem now is that when I close the program the value that generates to my `TextBox` is start always in 13020001. I want to retain the value that recently added and then increment it to +1 so I plan to display the current ID that just added to my DB using these :

```
  Dim querystring As String = "SELECT MAX(pIDNo) FROM dbo.Patients"

            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=####;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=####;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password=")
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(querystring, connection)
                connection.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    txtCurrentID.Text = reader.GetString(0)
                End While
                reader.Close()
```

I manage to display the current ID but the problem now is I can't increment it by 1.

Other problem : I try to copy the displayed value and just add it by one but another problem came up, the month and year doesn't change. If I reached the month 'MARCH' the value that generates is still

1302 + pnum1.text("D4") that supposed to be 1303 + pnum1.text("D4")

1302 is for FEBRUARY
1303 is for MARCH

could anyone have a solution with my problem?

Comment: you want the last inserted value?

Comment: I already have that. see the 

`SELECT MAX(pIDNo) FROM dbo.Patients`(to select the last inserted value) and the
`txtCurrentID.Text = reader.GetString` (to display it to my textBox)

Comment: so you just want to increment it ?

Comment: yeah I want the value generete an ID that will automatically increment the last value that just added to my DB and that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 While reader.Read       //you don't need that for aggregate functions. 
     txtCurrentID.Text = command.ExecuteScaler() //something like that... is enough 
     int p1num=integer.parse(txt.CurrentID.text.substring(4,4)) +1
 //  End While
 ...

txtPNumber.Text = Y.Text.ToString & M.Text.ToString & p1num.ToString("D4")
```

if you just want the date: then use `Date.Today`

```
       pNumber.Text = Today.Date.Month.ToString + " " + Today.Date.Year.ToString
```

IntelliSense is your first book so must use it. ;)

Comment: I will try this ok sir Arpit?

Comment: command.ExecuteScalar (has a blue line) says : 'ExecuteScaler' is not a member of 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' what does it means?

Comment: if I'm going to use a single label for year + date is it possible to use `Date.Today` ? without getting the specific day? just the year and months?

Comment: hey I used your `pNumber.Text = Today.Date.Month + Today.Date.Year` the result was `2015` what is this?

Comment: the result is : `220130000` when I add up the .toString

Comment: I dunno, what is 220130000 BTW? oh '2' for feb `2013` for current year + 0000

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24418/discussion-between-danjor-and-arpit)

Answer (score 1):

13020004 this is the last inserted value. can you tell us whats your Required value after this?

Comment: pls! don't ask clarification in ans.

Comment: 13020005 and so on.... but the other problem is when the month reach March 1 the value should be 1303+(p1num.toString("D4")) ... the value of p1num will stay incrementing.

Comment: Arpit, Without Clear understanding how exactly can I or ... suggest them!

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve `MAX(pIDNo)` to `String` value.

```
Dim value  = string.Empty
While reader.Read
    value = reader.GetString(0)
End While
```

After that you can parse `value` as you need:

```
dim year = value.Substring(0,2)
dim month = value.Substring(2,2)
dim patientId = value.Substring(4,4)
dim newPatientId as Integer = Integer.Parse(patientId) + 1
.......
```

**EDIT**
This code gives you exactly what you want:

```
txtCurrentID.Text = Today.Year.ToString().Substring(2,2) & Today.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & (Integer.Parse(value) + 1).ToString("D4")
```

Comment: sir Andrey what will be the output if I'm going to use your codes? can you give me some because It's kinda new to me, I don't use this kind of codes...

Comment: Well, you can try it. My code doesn't contain any viruses at all.

Comment: Index and length must refer to a location within the string
Parameter name : length

Comment: still the same problem _Index and length must refer to a location within the string_
Parameter name: length

I used your edited codes

Comment: @Danjor Remove `.Substring(4,4)` from `Integer.Parse(value.Substring(4,4)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24417/discussion-between-danjor-and-andrey-gordeev)

Answer (score 1):

Retrive the Patient ID from the DB and Spit it, assign to another Variable.
This Method works

```
dim p1num = patientId.Substring(4,7)
Dim M = Format(Now, "MM")
Dim Y = Format(Now, "yy") 
lblsample.Text = Y.ToString() & M.ToString() & p1num.ToString("D4")
```

Comment: 'patientID' is not declared. it maybe inaccessible due to protection level. what shoud I do with this?

Comment: patientID means the Last inserted record in DB, get that value and Assign it to a Variable of the Same name or something Different.! Mine is just a sample..!

Comment: thanks for helping sir Muthuram, I already have the answer for my program, and it run smoothly... thanks anyway GOD BLESS :)